# Which is the best way to find percentage change of list of values in a timeserie

Tags: statistics, siddhi

I have a series of timeseries data

```
delay(10)
espData=[value,100,1513298528793]
delay(10)
espData=[value,110,1513298528803]
delay(10)
espData=[value,120,1513298528813]
delay(10)
espData=[value,130,1513298528823]
delay(10)
espData=[value,140,1513298528833]
```

I am wondering weather slope calculation in linear regression will help me find the percentage change (negative/positive)

Answer (score 0):

User [sequence processing in Siddhi](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#sequence)

The following code will do

```
define stream InputStream (vlaue int, timestamp long);

from every  e1 = InputStream, e2 = InputStream
select (e2.vlaue - e1.vlaue) * 100.0/e1.vlaue as percentageChange, 
    e1.vlaue as oldVaule, e2.vlaue as newValue
insert into OutputStream;
```

Comment: what if i want to find the percentage change over a period of time say 5 mins.